# Windows setup up bad route

Tags: networking, windows-7, route

I am seeing a weird problem on a Windows 7 x64 PC.

The PC has two network interfaces:  10.0.7.80 and 169.254.198.30

For some reason when 169.254.X.X interface comes up Windows sets up incorrect route for it.

The `route print` command shows that packets for 169.254.X.X subnet will go to 10.0.7.80 interface:

```
169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link         10.0.7.80     30
```

I am not sure why Windows creates it.  It happens only on one PC in the office.  Other PCs setup routes correctly.

EX:

```
169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     169.254.40.79     286
```

Is there anything different in the settings?

If I execute `route add 169.254.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0. 169.254.198.30` command everything works fine, but I can't expect a user to do it mually every time they have network problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is no routing problem. Your NIC obviously doesn't get an IP via DHCP or you configured it wrong. Have a look at [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735):

> 169.254.0.0/16 - This is the "link local" block. As described in [RFC3927], it is allocated for communication between hosts on a single
> link. Hosts obtain these addresses by auto-configuration, such as when
> a DHCP server cannot be found.

Comment: That's correct.  The 10.0.7.80 interface is connected to the office network and gets its address from DCHP.  

I have just one other device connected directly to the second interface, there is no DHCP server.  Hence its address is in the 169.254.XX.XX range.  I would still expect them to communicate though.

Plus, why would only one PC have this issue?

Comment: I'd recommend either setting up DHCP for the second NICs or to configure them with static IPs, you shouldn't use `169.254.0.0/16` as IPs.

Comment: @AlexGdalevich, "_I would still expect them to communicate though._" No, you cannot route to or from the `169.254.0.0/16` network. That is expressly forbidden by the RFC: "_An IPv4 packet whose source and/or destination address is in the 169.254/16 prefix MUST NOT be sent to any router for forwarding, and any network device receiving such a packet MUST NOT forward it, regardless of the TTL in the IPv4 header._" and "_The non-forwarding rule means that hosts may assume that all 169.254/16 destination addresses are "on-link" and directly reachable._"